# How to receive FCM push notifications in service worker in Chrome Extension

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending an FCM push notification from a Firebase backend to a Chrome Extension. I get it to show successfully in my Chrome Extension when it's in focus. I want it to show even if the Extension isn't in focus, but I can't get the service worker that's supposed to handle the notification even to fire.

I followed the [Google tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive) to set up my JavaScript Chrome Extension client. I already tried [this solution](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/71) to not include a "notification" payload in my message, and [this solution](https://hexadix.com/push-notification-web-browser/) to register the worker manually (even though the tutorial doesn't say anything about either), but to no avail.

My service worker `firebase-messaging-sw.js` looks like this:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.2/firebase.js');

var config = {
  ...
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload.data);
  var notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

This is the POST request I use to send notifications (obviously with the correct SERVER_KEY and USER_TOKEN values):

```
POST /fcm/send HTTP/1.1
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=<SERVER_KEY>
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
    "data": {
        "title": "Firebase",
        "body": "Firebase is awesome",
        "click_action": "http://localhost:5000/",
        "icon": "http://localhost:5000/firebase-logo.png"
    },
    "to": "<USER_TOKEN>"
}
```

**How do I get the service worker to receive the push notification and display it?**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Jason I contacted Firebase team about this, all they said was "
Receiving FCM notifications from Chrome extensions should work using the [Push API](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/) since service workers are enabled on extensions". I dropped it and started moved to a different approach so I haven't tried it, but it's worth giving it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Push API](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/) in service worker (firebase-messaging-sw.js):

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.2/firebase-messaging.js');

var config = {
  ...
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

this.onpush = event => {
    console.dir(event.data.json());
    // Here you can use event.data to compose Notification
    // @see https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/#pushmessagedata-interface
};
```